# How to properly set up Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on an Android app with another developer, but I do not know how to properly set up the eclipse Android SDK thingy. The other developer has written some code, but I think my build path has not been set up properly, and so much of the code is underlined as an error.

For example, these import statements are not working:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

So, of course, that means that a lot of the other code will not work either. Could you please tell me how to set up the IDE so that the import statements will be successful?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have downloaded the sdk bundle:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk
Go to preferences in Eclipse and check the location is set to your sdk folder.
If this is not the problem then what errors is it giving you?